# Fourier tranform of Coulomb-like potential $1/|r-r'|$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential, fourier-transform, coulombs-law

I've found that Fourier transform of Coulomb potential $V= q/r$ is 
$F[V]= 4\pi q/k^2$.
Now I need to calculate fourier transform of function $1/|r-r'|$. And I exactly don't know how to operate with an absolute value $|r-r'|$.
Could anyone help?

Comment: Do you want to transform with respect to both variables or with respect to $R = r - r'$?

Comment: I need to make transform with respect to both variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: use the [Fourier shift theorem](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Shift_Theorem.html) (extended to 3D).